# Android: How to change the control type for Accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility

There are some controls in our app which we'd like to update the control type read out by Talkback.  For example: A TextView which would better be described as a link, or an ImageView that would better be described as a button.

We could simply update the content description to report out the desired control type, though I am wondering if there is a better way?  If there is another way, can it be done both through the view XML and dynamically in the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the type. It is called `roleDescription`. You would change it as follows:

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(yourView,
    object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v, info)
            info.roleDescription = "Button"
        }
})
```

(use string resources and translate the strings to all languages supported by your app)

This cannot be done via XML by default, but you could look into writing your own [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) for this.